# parent aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading elasticsearch documents. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/children-agg.html

It says,

> Parent-child supports a [children aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html) as a direct analog
>   to the nested aggregation discussed in [Nested Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html). A
>   parent aggregation (the equivalent of reverse_nested) is not
>   supported.

I'm just wondering why elasticsearch does not support parent aggregation. And how to implement it if requires. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I created PR https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/34210 which adds full support for parent-aggregations. It was included in time for Elasticsearch 6.6 and thus Elasticsearch now supports both parent -> child and also child -> parent aggregations.

---

See the discussion in the related issue at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9705, basically it seems to be too much effort/refactoring required and nobody invested this amount of work (yet).

I would expect that there are some technical difficulties which cannot be avoided easily here, thus making this feature hard to achieve.

Reading a number of related discussions, the following workarounds were mentioned:

- Denormalize data
- Application-side joins
- Nested objects

Nested can do a "reverse nested" aggregation and thus allows this, with the big disadvantage of nested documents that you always need to store the parent and all it's children in one go, which will be hard for some use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch does have a [parent aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-parent-aggregation.html) now, since about version 6.